# Angular 5 canActivate not working

Tags: angular

I'm trying to make an AuthGuard to check in every route if user is logged in. After a click in login button, I go to dashboard page and everything is ok. The problem is when I click in any other route by routerLink, the application reloads and redirect to login page again.

I'm tying to reproduce what this project does: [Angular-Routes](https://github.com/loiane/curso-angular2/blob/master/rotas/src/app/app.component.ts)

UPDATE 1:
Change implementation to use local storage and it work very well, anyway,  service data should not persist between routes if routes was changed by angular router?

this is my code:

auth.guard.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate, CanLoad, Route, Router, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router
  ) {

  }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
    return this.canAccess();
  }

  private canAccess(): boolean {

    if (this.authService.canAccess()) {
      return true;
    }
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    return false;
  }
}
```

auth.service.ts

```
import { EventEmitter, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  private user = false;
  logged = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  constructor(private router: Router) {

  }

  authUser() {
    this.user = true;
    this.logged.emit(true);
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
  }

  canAccess() {
    return this.user;
  }

}
```

app.routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { MidiaGalleryComponent } from './midia-gallery/midia-gallery.component';
import { BannerComponent } from './banner/banner.component';
import { NewsComponent } from './news/news.component';
import { SolutionComponent } from './solution/solution.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './guards/auth.guard';


const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  { path: 'galeria-midia',
    component: MidiaGalleryComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  { path: 'banners',
    component: BannerComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  { path: 'noticias',
    component: NewsComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  { path: 'solucoes',
    component: SolutionComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: '/dashboard' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {enableTracing: true})],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {

}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { NgSelectModule } from '@ng-select/ng-select';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

// Components
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { MidiaGalleryComponent } from './midia-gallery/midia-gallery.component';
import { BannerComponent } from './banner/banner.component';
import { SolutionComponent } from './solution/solution.component';
import { NewsComponent } from './news/news.component';

// Internal Modules
import { NewsModule } from './news/news.module';
import { SharedComponentsModule } from './shared-components/shared-components.module';
import { BannerModule } from './banner/banner.module';
import { SolutionModule } from './solution/solution.module';
import { MidiaGalleryModule } from './midia-gallery/midia-gallery.module';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routing.module';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { AuthGuard } from './guards/auth.guard';
import { HeaderComponent } from './template/header/header.component';
import { MenuComponent } from './template/menu/menu.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './template/footer/footer.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    MidiaGalleryComponent,
    BannerComponent,
    SolutionComponent,
    NewsComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    MenuComponent,
    FooterComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    NewsModule,
    SharedComponentsModule,
    BannerModule,
    SolutionModule,
    NgSelectModule,
    MidiaGalleryModule,
  ],
  providers: [AuthService, AuthGuard],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

login template

```
<div class="vertical-align login-background text-center" data-animsition-in="fade-in" data-animsition-out="fade-out">
  <div class="page-content vertical-align-middle animation-slide-top animation-duration-1">
    <div class="brand">
      <img class="brand-img" src="../../assets/images/img_login_logo.png">
    </div>
    <p class="login-subtitle">Plataforma de conteúdo Unicred</p>
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" name="email" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="inputPassword">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" name="password"
               placeholder="Senha">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group clearfix">
        <div class="checkbox-custom checkbox-inline checkbox-primary float-left">
          <input type="checkbox" id="inputCheckbox" name="remember">
          <label class="remember-me" for="inputCheckbox">Lembre-me</label>
        </div>
        <a class="float-right forgot-password" href="forgot-password.html">Esqueceu a senha?</a>
      </div>
      <button (click)="onSubmit()" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Entrar</button>
    </form>

    <footer class="page-copyright page-copyright-inverse">
      <div class="text-capitalize" >company</div>
      <div class="text-capitalize">© 2018. .</div>
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

Login Component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.authService.authUser();
  }

}
```

routerLink Example:

```
 <a class="animsition-link" routerLink="/galeria-midia" routerLinkActive="active">
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "su-backoffice",
  "title": "Backoffice Site",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "keywords": [
    "css",
    "js",
    "less",
    "responsive",
    "web",
    "admin",
    "bootstrap",
    "scss"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^0.30.1",
    "angular-froala-wysiwyg": "^2.7.6",
    "angular2-lightbox": "^1.3.0",
    "animsition": "^4.0.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.4",
    "bootstrap-datepicker": "^1.7.1",
    "bootstrap-hover-dropdown": "^2.2.1",
    "bootstrap-markdown": "^2.10.0",
    "bootstrap-maxlength": "^1.6.0",
    "bootstrap-select": "^1.12.4",
    "bootstrap-sweetalert": "^1.0.1",
    "bootstrap-table": "^1.11.2",
    "bootstrap-tagsinput": "^0.7.1",
    "bootstrap-tokenfield": "^0.12.0",
    "bootstrap-touchspin": "^3.1.1",
    "bootstrap-treeview": "^1.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "jquery-asBreadcrumbs": "^0.2.3",
    "jquery-asColor": "^0.3.6",
    "jquery-asColorPicker": "^0.4.4",
    "jquery-asGradient": "^0.3.3",
    "jquery-asHoverScroll": "^0.3.6",
    "jquery-asPaginator": "^0.3.3",
    "jquery-asPieProgress": "^0.4.7",
    "jquery-asProgress": "^0.2.4",
    "jquery-asRange": "^0.3.4",
    "jquery-asScrollable": "^0.4.10",
    "jquery-asScrollbar": "^0.5.7",
    "jquery-asSpinner": "^0.4.3",
    "jquery-contextmenu": "^2.6.3",
    "jquery-knob": "^1.2.11",
    "jquery-match-height": "^0.7.2",
    "jquery-mousewheel": "^3.1.13",
    "jquery-placeholder": "^2.3.1",
    "jquery-selective": "^0.3.5",
    "jquery-slidePanel": "^0.3.5",
    "jquery-strength": "^0.2.5",
    "jquery-tabledit": "^1.0.0",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
    "jquery-wizard": "^0.4.4",
    "jquery.mmenu": "^6.1.8",
    "ng2-dnd": "^5.0.2",
    "ngx-mydatepicker": "^2.4.4",
    "peity": "^3.2.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.12.9",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.5.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.2.17",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "autoprefixer": "^7.2.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: i suggest to use localStorage to store isLoggedin property and use it to check if the user is logged

Comment: i will try to use local storage, but i did what this project does, https://github.com/loiane/curso-angular2/blob/master/rotas/src/app/app.component.ts, and it work hear

Comment: I'd suggest you find a better source of inspiration. EventEmitter should **only** be used for `@Output` fields of components. And no, it probably doesn't work in this project: what you store in a service is only stored in memory. If you reload the page, the memory is wiped out, and you restart from scratch, and the user is thus not considered as logged in anymore.

Comment: oh, ok, i will do this, thanks, but a service data should not persist between routes if routes was changed by angular router?

Comment: Yes, it should. If the application reloads when clicking on a router link, then you have another problem. Check for errors in the console.

Comment: @JBNizet i did, and log was normal, but after log everything (and i activated enableTracing) the page reloads without any explanation, it curious that with local storage it don't happens anymore.